# JOIN two SELECT statement results from two different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a code to join two statements each from different table and conditions, as follows:

the first statement:

```
select TO_CHAR(Entry_date, 'MON.YYYY') AS Months, count(Customer_id) "Count Customer"
from table1
where  entry_date >= TO_DATE('01.01.1900', 'DD.MM.YYYY') 
     AND entry_date <= TO_DATE('31.12.2017', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
     and Customer_status = 'Active'
group by TO_CHAR(entry_date,'MON.YYYY')

order by to_date(TO_CHAR(entry_date, 'MON.YYYY'),'MON.YYYY')
```

The second statement:

```
select count (order_id) "Order"
from table2
where leave_date >= TO_DATE('01.01.1900', 'DD.MM.YYYY') 
         AND leave_date <= TO_DATE('31.12.2017', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
    group by TO_CHAR(leave_date,'MON.YYYY')

    order by to_date(TO_CHAR(leave_date, 'MON.YYYY'),'MON.YYYY')
```

the result should look like this

```
Months           Count Customer      Order
Jan. 2017              15              0
Feb. 2017              1               8
Mar. 2017              30              10
```

The order should be dependent on the Months that were stated in the first statement.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write this as:

```
select yyyymm, sum(cust_count) as cust_count, sum(num_orders) as num_orders
from ((select to_char(entry_date, 'YYYY-MM') as yyyymm, count(*) as cust_count, 0 as num_orders
       from table1
       where entry_date >= date '1900-01-01' and
             entry_date < date '2018-01-01' and
             Customer_status = 'Active'
      group by to_char(entry_date, 'YYYY-MM')
     ) union all
     (select to_char(leave_date, 'YYYY-MM') as yyyymm, 0,
             count(*) as num_orders
      from table2
      where leave_date >= date '1900-01-01' and 
            leave_date < date '2018-01-31'
      group by to_char(leave_date, 'YYYY-MM')
     )
    ) tt
group by yyyymm
order by yyyymm;
```

Notes on some changes:

- The use of `date` rather than `to_char()` with date constants.
- The use of the format "YYYY-MM", which orders correctly.  (You don't have to use it but it recommended.)
- The `union all` brings all the data together.  In Oracle, you can also use a `full outer join`, but that requires more use of `coalesce()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot worked as I am expecting, but the dates are ordered as follows:
April 2015
April 2016
Jun 2015
Jun 2016
Instead of :
April 2015
Jun 2015
April 2016
Jun 2016
Thanks in advance

Comment: @Tarek85 . . . They will be ordered correctly if you use the format `'YYYY-MM'`.

Comment: in my oracle version, this format is not possible. it accepts Mon.YYYY format.

Comment: @Tarek85 . . . You can `order by min(leave_date)`.